# Compare tables between two MDF files

Tags: c#, sql-server, file

I am attempting to synchronizing tables in two different `.MDF` files. After successfully creating a datatable for the first file I get an error when trying to create the second:

> Cannot attach file 'E:\JVT-Inventory.mdf' as database 'JVT-Inventory' because this database name is already attached with file 'C:\Database\JVT-Inventory.mdf'

I have created separate procedures for each connection to create the tables then disposed the connection. Both the datatable and adapter are global variables to be used in my routines to compare the tables. None of the online research seems to apply to what I am trying to accomplish.

```
        string conString;
        conString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;attachdbfilename=" + @txtPath.Text + ";Initial Catalog=JVT-Inventory;integrated security=True";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            daRemote = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblProduct ORDER BY keyPartNo", connection);
            SqlCommandBuilder cbRemote = new SqlCommandBuilder(daRemote);
            daRemote.Fill(dtRemote);
            connection.Dispose();
```

This connection is made to a file on a flash drive.
The issue appears to be that the MDF file remains open until I exit the application.  My question now is, how do I close the MDF file from within my application?

Comment: The error message is self-explaining. DB names on the server must be **unique**.

Comment: There is no server.  The application attaches to the database file from one location on the hard drive.  I want to compare that to another database file on a flash drive.  Even after closing and clearing the connection it appears the database remains in memory, therefore creating your "self-explaining" (obvious) duplication.

Comment: There **is** SQL Server (*LocalDB*) to which you `attach` your `.mdf`.

Comment: Alex, since the (LocalDB) IS a server and I have two separate files, it would stand to reason that I have two separate servers.  Therefore, the DB name on each server is unique.  The issue I had was one I still don't understand because I disposed the connections but the name remained (somehow) in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching many articles about working with databases I figured out the follow:

```
            SqlConnection cnRemoteBye = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmdRemoteBye = new SqlCommand();
            cnRemoteBye.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True";
            cmdRemoteBye.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [JVT-Inventory] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE \n\r exec sp_detach_db @dbname = [JVT-Inventory]";
            cmdRemoteBye.Connection = cnRemoteBye;
            cnRemoteBye.Open();
            cmdRemoteBye.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnRemoteBye.Close();
```